# Datetime Format and calculation

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple system which would get the current time and get another time after few secs, then see the difference with both of the times, so it's 2 seconds. So what I need is the other format like this > YEAR,MONTH,DAY HOUR:MIN.
This is the code which I use for this purpose, but **in brackets there are just an example of the format I need**.

```
a = datetime.datetime.now( %Y, %m %d %H:%M)
time.sleep(2)
b = datetime.datetime.now( %Y, %m %d %H:%M)
print(b-a)
print(a)
print(b)
```

Comment: Look into `timedelta` -> https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

Comment: I can also use this to get the time, but I can't do the maths then. 'Reg_Tikslus_Laikas = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", time.localtime())'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thing strftime is what you're looking for

```
import datetime
import time

a = datetime.datetime.now()
time.sleep(2)
b = datetime.datetime.now()
print(b-a)
print(a.strftime("%Y, %m, %d %H:%M"))
print(b.strftime("%Y, %m, %d %H:%M"))
```

prints

```
0:00:02.001719
2019, 09, 04 15:17
2019, 09, 04 15:17
```

For more formats, you can see strftime reference: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/strftime.

Comment: Mhm, this works fine. What about creating if function for example. The minimum difference is 5 sec?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a `datetime.datetime` instance to a string formatted to your liking using the `strftime()` function. For instance, to print with your preferred formatting you could do the following:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> print(a.strftime("%Y, %m %d %H:%M")
2019, 09 04 17:11
```

Subtracting two dates will yield a `datetime.timedelta` object, you can convert this to the number of seconds using the `total_seconds()` function:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> from time import sleep
>>> a = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> sleep(2)
>>> b = datetime.datetime.now()
>>> delta = b - a
>>> print(delta.total_seconds())
2.001301
```

Comment: That's what I was looking and trying to do:) Also if I will be using larger time differences how should I see the difference in hours?

Comment: Looking into the documentation (https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta) the `timedelta` object has no dedicated function for this, so I would simply take `delta.total_seconds() / 3600`.

Comment: Is it possible to create an if statement for checking the difference?

Comment: I am not sure if I understand, do you mean you would want to use the difference in seconds in the condition of the `if`-statement?